# ExactOnline API en OData

Tags: php, odata, exact-online

I am struggling with the API of Exact Online.
Using this example code to retrieve information of the server:

```
$response = $exactApi->sendRequest("crm/Accounts?$filter=substringof('test', Name) eq true', 'get');
```

Above returns a Bad Request. Anyone got a clue how to fix this?

The function 'send request':

```
    public function sendRequest($url, $method, $payload = NULL)
{
    if ($payload && !is_array($payload)) {
        throw new ErrorException('Payload is not valid.');
    }

    if (!$accessToken = $this->initAccessToken()) {
        throw new ErrorException('Access token was not initialized');
    }

    $requestUrl = $this->getRequestUrl($url, array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    ));

    // Base cURL option
    $curlOpt = array();
    $curlOpt[CURLOPT_URL] = $requestUrl;
    $curlOpt[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = TRUE;
    $curlOpt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = TRUE;
    $curlOpt[CURLOPT_HEADER] = false;

    if ($method == self::METHOD_POST) {

        $curlOpt[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json', 
            'access_token:' . $accessToken, 
            'Content-length: ' . strlen(json_encode($payload))
        );
        $curlOpt[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = json_encode($payload);
        $curlOpt[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = strtoupper($method);
    }
    $curlOpt[CURLOPT_ENCODING] = '';
    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, $curlOpt);

    return curl_exec($curlHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this.

```
crm/Accounts?$select=Name&$filter=substringof('Lennert',Name) : OK

crm/Accounts?$select=Name&$filter=substringof('Lennert', Name) eq true : NOK, error 400

crm/Accounts?\$select=Name&$filter=substringof(Name, 'Lennert') eq true : NOK, error 400
```

First option works but is not according to OData v2 specifications which Exact Online uses. Will be discussed with development to see what can be done for this.

Comment: This has been registered as future improvement. In the meantime please use option 1.